# ERROR running force:source:deploy: Deploy failed

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli-auth

I keep getting ERROR running force:source:deploy: Deploy failed.

I just follow the instructions right [here](https://github.com/trailheadapps/ebikes-lwc#installing-e-bikes-using-a-developer-edition-org).

This is my current org:

```
ALIAS     USERNAME                      ORG ID              CONNECTED STATUS
────────  ────────────────────────────  ──────────────────  ────────────────
ebikesDE  simon.guillen@broad-path.com  00D2v000000RupWEAS  Connected
```

My domain name is simon-bp-developer-edition.ap15.force.com. I also deleted the Product picklist from the Case Object and logged in with the alias ebikesDE using this command: `sfdx force:auth:web:login -a ebikesDE`.

When I deploy using the command `sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app/main/default -u ebikesDE` I kept getting the Deploy failed error..

It doesn't specify the reason why I get this error but I can't seem to get out of it. I applied changes on `E_Bikes.site-meta.xml` and `E-Bikes Profile.profile`. Please help me on this issue.

Comment: Did you check the deployment status in your org? There may be additional information there.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while Deploying when i was completing the Trailhead. After checking the "**Deployment Status**" in my Dev(Trailhead) Org, I figured out that my `Product__c` field from Case object had not been deleted also there appeared a typo in E_Bikes.site-meta.xml, Please reconfirm the `E_Bikes.site-meta.xml` and `E-Bikes Profile.profile`

Refer to the Deployment status in Salesforce Org to get more information on Deployment failure.